# MVC3 EF5 query plan caching

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have MVC3 project with target framework 4.0. I am developing under VS2010. I have .NET 4.5 installed of my machine.

I read that EF4 and DbContext does not support compiled query and query plan caching.

So i just changed referenced library from EF4 to EF5, because this version caches query by default and i am still using MVC3 and VS2010.

In VS2010 i cannot set target framework 4.5  for my web project.

SO my question is:

How can i determine, if EF5 in my MVC3 really caches LINQ queries? Is there any static class, which contains these queries or?

Comment: You need to be targeting .NET 4.5 in order to use EF5.  If you install EF5, it will simply be EF 4.4

Comment: In web.config i have targetFramework="4.5". But in project properties through VS2010 there is version 4. There is no 4.5 option in combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is, that .NET 4.0 with EF4.4 does not support autocompiled queries.

Visit [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/190c77fe-39dc-487d-a02a-b0a6326e657b/mvc3-ef5-query-plan-caching?forum=netfxbcl#d101c270-4aa3-434b-9f9a-e246d6d4c1fd)